# How does the luxury index affect demand?

Tags: capitalism-2

Each product in *Capitalism 2* has a necessity index and a luxury index.

I understand what the necessity index does: necessity of 10 (i.e. 100%) means no change in demand during recessions, high necessity means low decrease in demand during recessions, and low necessity means high decrease in demand during recessions. However, I don't know what the luxury index does. How does the luxury index affect demand?

For reference, below is a screenshot of Capitalism 2's product database where the luxury index for each product appears in the column named "LUXURY":

[image: Capitalism 2 product database]

<sub>Source: [editable game - Capitalism II and Capitalism Lab Forum](http://www.capitalism2.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31)</sub>

The full table is also available: http://www.adammil.net/files/112/ITEM.html

Comment: Staff at Enlight did not want to answer in the forum (for understandable reasons): [Impact of the luxury index on demand?](https://www.capitalism2.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7178)